# UITableViewCell, two cells are both getting an accessory view

Tags: ios, uitableview

Situation: When a user selects a cell, a button is added to that cell. When they select a new cell, the button is removed from the previous cell and added to the new cell. That works. The problem is when more data is added to the table. So lets say there are 20 cells, then I add another 20 cells. I then select the first cell, however the button is added to cell 1 AND cell  21. The select delegate method only registers the first one being selected though.

From my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
if (self.selectedCell) {
    self.selectedCell.accessoryView = nil;
    self.selectedCell = nil;
}

UIButton *downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[downloadButton setTitle:@"Download" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[downloadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 34)];

self.selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

self.selectedCell.accessoryView = downloadButton;
[self.selectedCell setNeedsDisplay];
```

In my method that adds more data to the table I end with:

```
if(self.selectedCell){
    self.selectedCell.accessoryView = nil;
    self.selectedCell = nil;
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cells are reused. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you're forgetting to clear `accessoryView`. When the cell is reused, the `accessoryView` comes along.

A technique I like is to set the `accessoryView` in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. This is called right before the cell is put on the screen. You can then do something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (cell.isSelected) {
    cell.accessoryView = self.downloadButton; // No reason to create a new one every time, right?
  }
  else {
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue in one of my projects. You can also set the accessory view outside the cell creation (avoids reusing cell with accessoryView).

Comment: hey bill burgess.. i am also stuck up with this issue.. can u tell me how to set up accessory view outside the cell creation?

Comment: Does your reuse of the same `cell.accessoryView = self.downloadbutton` instance actually work? Seems to cause a deadlock in the UI:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190675/how-to-set-the-table-view-cell-accessory-view-to-retain-a-previously-initialized