# multiple UITableViewCell cells accessoryView referencing same view fails

Tags: ios, uitableview

In a UITableViewController I am instantiating UITableViewCells where some cells are highlighted by an accessoryView.  For me, this works:

```
// works for me
UIImageView *favoriteImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];
[cell setAccessoryView:favoriteImageView];
```

It seems wasteful to me to instantiate the same view repeatedly for multiple cells; however when I attempt to re-use the same view as the accessoryView of multiple cells my app fails in a miserable way (completely black screen, no views presented) I haven't been able to debug.  Whether I declare favoriteImageView as a static inside the method such as

```
// doesn't work for me
static UIImageView *favoriteImageView = nil;        
if (!favoriteImageView) 
    favoriteImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];

[cell setAccessoryView:favoriteImageView];
```

Or declare it as an ivar and define it in init such that I wind up with:

```
// doesn't work for me
[cell setAccessoryView:[self favoriteImageView]];
```

In these two not-working cases, when one cell has its accessoryView set, it displays properly. As soon as I mark a second row such that the accessoryView would be set to reference the same view, the whole thing hangs up.

What are the requirements for constructing a UIView and/or configuring a UITableViewCell in such a way that the same UIView may be referenced as the accessoryView of multiple UITableViewCells?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190675/how-to-set-the-table-view-cell-accessory-view-to-retain-a-previously-initialized

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView extends from UIView. And a UIView can't be in two or more places at the same time.
Therefor, if you try to display an UIImageView in two or more cells at the same time, it won't work. You need an UIImageView for each cell on screen.

I suggest that for each cell you create the UIImageView. The tableviewcells will be reused alongside with their accessoryview, so I wouldn't worry too much about performance or memoryproblems.

Comment: Than you for your response and it makes sense to me.  However, I've seen related code snippets elsewhere on Stack Overflow that imply that a view can be reused for an accessoryView. For example in #1 answer to this question, the accessoryView appears to be set from an ivar and there's even a comment "No reason to create a new one every time, right?" Is it right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390866/uitableviewcell-two-cells-are-both-getting-an-accessory-view

Comment: Interesting, although I'm not quite sure if that's working code. Worth a shot I guess. As far as I know you need to create one for each cell. Which is still not a concern since at most maybe 7 will be made in practise. I suggest to try my answer, I'm pretty sure it will work. Then if possible, optimize it to 1 view